# Core Plot build error while using with Pods

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, cocoapods

I am running into an issue where I am using CorePlot API with Pods (recently added CorePlot in Pod file) in my project and every time I try to build the project for Device/Simulator I get a couple of errors from `CPTAnimation.h`

```
too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 3
                            setterMethod(boundObject, boundSetter, buffer);

too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 3
                            setterMethod(boundObject, boundSetter, tweenedValue);
```

As mentioned on this commit it has already been fixed [here](https://github.com/IngmarStein/core-plot/commit/3413d8b7fa382921a918e7801a22e614a17b8bbf?diff=split)

I am using `0.36.3` of cocoa pods version on my machine. How do I get access to this build on Cocoapods ? I tried to fix these errors manually and was able to run the project but When I retried after I nuked everything and reinstalled Cocoapods with a subsequent Pod update,I lost all my previous changes. I feel this is not the correct way of using libraries with Cocoapods

For more info please refer to the screenshot

[image]

Can someone guide me in right direction to fix these error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently fixed some Core Plot issues related to CocoaPods. Use the following line in your podfile to get the latest Core Plot code:

```
pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git'
```

There is a new header file that can be used from iOS or the Mac. On iOS, you can continue to use the old `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h`, if you prefer.

```
#import "CorePlot.h"
```

Comment: Thanks , That fixed the problem and pulled the latest code from github. Just to point out when I do a Pod update I see - Installing CorePlot (99.99.99), guess this means this is the most latest version available.

Answer (score 0):

For installing PodNew project or existing project

1>  Sudo gem Update – system

2>  Sudo gem Install cocoapods

3>  Pod stepup

4>  “Go to Project folder”

5>  pod init

6>  open –a xcode podfile

7>  add the framework what u need

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I have investigated so far this is an issue with the current XCode & cocoapods versions (XCode 6.2 and 0.36.3) and available version of CorePlot from CocoaPods (1.5.1). All other libraries that I have integrated so far are working fine.